# CSS Sprite Alignment in LI where images should be on the right

Tags: css, alignment, background-image, sprite

I can't seem to get the sprite to be aligned on right of the LI element

```
<li class="menuItems">
      <div style="background: #ffffff url('pixmaps/glyphicons.png') no-repeat 
-553px -56px; height:27px;width:29px;background-position: -30px 0px;">
        <a href="#"  >Streams</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

[image: Weird alignment]

I tried with and without the div - putting the sprite-background on the li or the a element but behaving almost the same.
Changing the li's padding (a often read solution) would mess up my -Link, which should remain at this very position.

So what is the proper way to solve this? Sure I could modify the sprite and add a huge transparent space, but thats not really the way to go as my sprite includes the whole glyphiconset (400+ Icons + in addition all the Icons in a darker tone for rollover).

Thank you!

Comment: You can't cross-browser clip a background image. If the element is bigger than the size of the sprite, you're going to have problems. You either need to add padding to the sprite, or generate a separate sprite _just_ for those icons, or create a separate element to contain the icon.

Comment: Hey Christian, how would I achieve the seperate element to show the Icons? I tried that but to no result. Whatever I used I was pushed to the next line (div) or wouldnt just show at all (span). Any examples flying around the web? Thanks

Comment: I just noticed that I used display:block somewhere which could cause this behavior. Have to check when I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to leave this as comment, but it's actually more of an answer.

If you want to use an extra element, I generally use spans. Set it to `display: block`, with both the `height` and `width` set as well (to the exact size of the icon). If you don't want it to affect the layout, set it to `position: absolute`, and to position it, do something like `right: 10px; top: 10px` etc. If you use `position: absolute`, you'd also need to make sure the parent has positioning set too, like `position: relative`.

Full example:

```
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  background: url('pixmaps/glyphicons.png') no-repeat -553px -56px; /* set the offset to the exact position of your icon */
}

.menuItems {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hallo Christian, this would actually have solved my problem but I switched over to "awesome icons" to have some easier and more transparent Icon handling (hover color change and so on).

Comment: What's awesome icons? Is it a library, and could you provide a link to it? It would be great to see what you're actually using.

Comment: That is amazing. Nice find!